# why different output when run program compiled with gcc and clang

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, clang, value-categories

I came across this [example](https://godbolt.org/z/z6q3WeGTj) below when watching video about c++:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

struct S {
    S() { std::cout << 'a'; }
    S(const S&) { std::cout << 'b'; }
    S(S&&) { std::cout << 'c'; }
};

template <typename T>
S f(T&& t) { return t; }

int main() {
    S s{};
    f(s);
    f(std::move(s));
}
```

At first I thought it is pretty clear that std::move(s) cast s into rvalue reference and the template is instantiated as `S f(S&& t) {return t;}`. The argument is an rvalue so when passing parameter `S(S&&)` is called, and the output is 'abc'. The output is 'abc' as expected when compiled with compiler **x86-64 clang 15.0.0**. But when compiled with **x86-64 gcc 12.2**, it output 'abb'.

Why it output 'b' instead of 'c' when compiled with gcc? Is this something about UB or implementation dependent? Or something else I do not know?

***Edit***: It seems when the template is modified to this:

```
template <typename T>
S f(T&& t) { return std::forward<T>(t); }
```

gcc start to output 'abc' just as clang(same version as stated above).
I don't know how it is related to std::foward.
And here is the [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hR8foAWrmCs&t=3768s) I was watching. The example appears about at 54 min.

Comment: How do you compile, what compiler flags do you use?

Comment: `S f(T&& t) { return t; }` - this is up to a compiler whether to move `t`.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/move_constructor <- there is some variation around c++17, adding `--std=c++2a` to gcc produces abc

Comment: @273K I just run it on ‘Compiler Explorer' and used default compile flags. There is a link above which links to the example code on ‘Compiler Explorer'.

Comment: You might want `T f(T&& t) { return t; }`

Comment: Does this fall under [copy elision](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_elision) (NRVO)?

Comment: @Eljay Probably not. I tried to add -fno-elide-constructors flag to disable RVO, things still looks the same.

Comment: How do you compile, what compiler flags do you use?

Comment: @Eljay just default flags except -fno-elide-constructors

Comment: @SICSU with `forward` it's just `S f(S&& t) { return (S&&)(t); }` i.e.  `S f(S&& t) { return std::move(t); }` why you surprise compiler use the move constructor?

Comment: @SICSU I'd suggest remove the update to keep the question focus (I'd also remove the `const S&` case and remove the template altogether)

Answer (score 2):

Originally in C++17 (and before) the correct answer was `abb`.

The specialization of `f` used in the last call looks like this:

```
S f<S>(S&& t) { return t; }
```

Normally the name of a variable, regardless of its type, is a lvalue and so overload resolution should choose the copy constructor here to construct the return value.

However, return statements whose operand is a (possibly parenthesized) id-expression have special rules where, under certain circumstances, overload resolution is done first as if the operand was a rvalue, even if it isn't, and only if this overload resolution failed, normal overload resolution would be attempted. If this applied to your situation, then `return t;` would still use the move constructor.

In C++17 one of the requirements for this special behavior was that id-expression names a local variable which is an *object*, not a reference. Therefore it wouldn't apply here.

For C++20 this has been changed with [P0527](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/397) to include local variables of rvalue reference type.

It seems that GCC implemented this change to apply only for C++20 and later modes (you get `abc` with `-std=c++20`), while Clang seems to have applied it also to older C++ modes as a defect report.

The [commit message](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=91427) to GCC 11 implementing the change mentions that this *should* be a defect report against earlier C++ versions as well, but that they want to gather some experience with the impact of this change. It seems they haven't yet implemented for modes below `-std=c++20`.

For C++23 the rules were further simplified so that there are not two overload resolution phases anymore. Instead id-expressions are now simply xvalue expressions instead of lvalue expressions in these special situations. This change was made by [P2266](https://github.com/cplusplus/papers/issues/968).